# Video upload is not being acknowledge as an attachment in Bot Framework SDK 4

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have this code that works yesterday. Its simple request for a video file upload, validate if the file is in a video format and then save it.

The prompt for video is

```
var promptOptions = {
            prompt: 'Upload a video',
            retryPrompt: 'The attachment must be a video file.'
        };
        return await step.prompt(VID_PROMPT, promptOptions);
```

where VID_PROMPT is an AttachmentPrompt:

`this.addDialog(new AttachmentPrompt(VID_PROMPT, this.videoValidator));`

and the validator, videoValidator's code is:

```
async videoValidator(promptContext) {
        //for back end cheking
        console.log("\n\r Message Type:" + promptContext.context._activity.type);
        console.log("\n\r Message:" + JSON.stringify(promptContext.context._activity.channelData.message));       
        /***************************/
        if (promptContext.recognized.succeeded) {
            var attachments = promptContext.recognized.value;
            var validImages = [];

            attachments.forEach(attachment => {
                if (attachment.contentType === 'video/mp4' || attachment.contentType === 'video/x-msvideo' || attachment.contentType === 'video/mpeg' || attachment.contentType === 'video/3gpp' || attachment.contentType === 'video/3gpp2') {
                    validImages.push(attachment);
                }
            });

            promptContext.recognized.value = validImages;

            // If none of the attachments are valid videos, the retry prompt should be sent.
            return !!validImages.length;
        }
        else {
            await promptContext.context.sendActivity('No attachments received. Please attach video file.');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Again, this worked fine yesterday (with the same code) but today, whenever I upload a video:
[image]

It would prompt **No attachments received. Please attach video file from my validator**
So I looked in the back and saw this:

[image]

Which says that the message received is doesn't contain an attachment, and of course AttachmentPrompt will see this and **promptContext.recognized.succeeded will be false thus executing the else clause in my videoValidator**.

Now, I tried uploading a picture, just to check if it would recognize an attachment file type:
[image]

And the message **The attachment must be a video file.** shows when it recognize I uploaded an attachment but the file type isn't video. And this is the back data:

[image]

How do I fix this. I didn't change anything,just suddenly didn't work. Please help. Thanks!

PS. I use botbuilder 4.11.0.

UPDATE: I checked directline channel and its working fine. It just doesn't work on Facebook channel I guess?

UPDATE: Now, even images aren't recognized as attachments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to FB webhooks (and is now working) see this thread: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/393441492018560/